Identify a horror with a pair of old farmers capturing people for meat
There was this old pair of farmers that were capturing the people for meat. They were burying them in the ground leaving the heads above the ground and then they were ripping their heads off with the tractor (I guess this was a picture on the cover). I remember also the scene with killing a man with a glue - putting a super-glue on his mouth and nose and guy suffocated. 
God, this all sounds awful.

Is it Motel Hell, (1980)?

The victims are restrained, then placed in a 'secret garden,’ buried
  up to their necks, and have their vocal cords cut to prevent them from
  screaming. They are kept in the ground and fed until they are ready
  for harvest.



yes, that's it! thanks:)
